# How to write string date value in import.sql file so that Hibernate can create and insert into MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have simple class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "date_time", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime date_time;

}
```

In my import.sql file, I have following:

```
INSERT INTO todo_project.task ( active, date_time, title, done) VALUES ( true, 'some-string-for-date-time', 'do homework', false);
```

What to set for `some-string-for-date-time`?

Comment: The easiest way would be:  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Twistleton Thank you so much on answer. However, do you perhaps know, how to write some specific date? Lets say something like this: '25-06-2020' ? Is it possible to leave out time portion?

Comment: Sure, but use LocalDate if you leave out the time portion.

Comment: And for mySQL: CURDATE() or a string with '2020-06-25' - But it depends on the time zone and the settings

Comment: INSERT INTO todo_project.task ( active, date_time, title, done) VALUES ( true, '2017-10-20', 'do homework', false);

Comment: @Twistleton God only know what I've been typing so for..your way works..Tho, till now I was working with LocalDateTime, but I switched it to LocalDate, I hope my professor won't ask for time constraint :D Thanks man

Comment: Certainly it is also possible to load timestamps. But I have never used it before. Good luck with your professor.